# How to slice specifc part of a string JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to slice a specific part of a string, but could not find any information on it.
I want to remove the first set of 00s and : from **10:00:00 AM** without removing the AM so **10:00AM**.

I could only find out how to slice from the back or front using -,+ symbols but not from the middle.

EDIT - Only want var  'dt' sliced not looking for a solution for other time values.

```
var dt = 10:00:00 AM
const result1 = dt.toLocaleString().slice(Number Here);
console.log(result1)
//want the result to be 10:00 AM
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of regular expressions?

Comment: Your code has an error on the first line.  Do you want variable "dt" to be a Date or String object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```js
const dt = '10:00:00 AM';

const result1 = dt.slice(0, 3) + dt.slice(6);

console.log(result1);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work with `9:00:00 AM` though.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @LuisMaximus sure, but are you looking for a generic solution to support all time values or only a way to use a splice for a string?

Comment: only for a specific string

Comment: Basically, it's a concatenation of two parts: substring 0-2 and substring 6-end

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
var dt = '10:00:00 AM'
const result1 = dt.toLocaleString().split(" ")[0].slice(0, -3) +" "+ dt.toLocaleString().split(" ")[1];
console.log(result1)
```